# Converting numeric value to English Text in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an application printing out invoices using Crystal Reports. The application is installed on PCs with different regional setting.

Now, if I use Crystal Report's TOWORDS() function, the resulting string are displayed in the language specified by user's PC. As an example, if a Chinese user prints out the invoice, Crystal Report will display the numeric string in Chinese. (which is not what we wanted.)

Obviously, changing the regional setting in users PC is not an option for us. My question is how can I force Crystal Reports to convert the numeric value to English text?

Answer (score 1):

Check these. Theres a lot of information on this topic that you can try.

[How to achieve localization in crystal reports](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3281788)

[Localized Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887433/localized-crystal-reports)

[Crystal reports setting for Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829249/crystal-reports-setting-for-language)