# How to convert numbers to Arabic words in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to convert given value to Arabic words using crystal report
I tried to use toWords function but I got English words .

```
ProperCase( ToWords(878000, 0) )
```

Does anyone Know how to get Arabic words?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting numeric value to English Text in Crystal Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965924/converting-numeric-value-to-english-text-in-crystal-reports)

Comment: Converting numbers to arabic words requires complex logic. Here is a link to a discussion where code logic is provided in a clear way for a case with no decimals and no currency names:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1372575.aspx?Spell+numbers+in+arabic You can implement the same logic in a Crystal formula.
If currency choice and decimals are involved, things get more complex. At least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs (User Function Libraries) listed here: http://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl provides a function for this, including handling currency.